# Trigger message when amplitude exceeds value

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to replicate some Matlab code in Python, here is my Matlab code:

```matlab
for k = 1:N
    if x(k) > 0.6 %triggers, when Amplitude is above 0.6
       timeOver = ['Abnormal reading detected at Time ', num2str(t(k)), 's. Please change cutting tool !!']; % creating a warning sign to display when abnormality is present
       disp(timeOver) % displaying of warning sign
       h = msgbox(timeOver,'Warning','warn');

       break % 'break' command for stopping of 'for' loop
    end
end
```

I made the following replacements:

- `for k = 1:N` changed to `for k in numpy.arange(0, N, 1)`
- `if x(k) > 0.6` changed to `if x.k > 0.6`

I realised that while in Matlab, `disp(k)` would produce values while in Python `print(k)` would produce 0.0

However, the for loop in Matlab produces a message while Python does not produce anything.

Comment: What do you think `x.k` means in Python? I'm a Matlabber but I think you mean `x[k]`...

Comment: yes you are right. I confused variable with function. Thank you for replying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should solve the issue:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10)  # some values of x; replace it with your values of x
t = np.arange(1, 11) - (np.random.rand(10) - 0.5)  # simulated, not equally spaced timestamps; replace it with your values of t

for idx, val in enumerate(x):
    if val > 0.6:  # triggers, when Amplitude is above 0.6
        print('Abnormal reading detected at Time ' + str(t[idx]) + 's. Please change cutting tool !!')
        break  # 'break' command for stopping of 'for' loop
```

Comment: what is the use of  `- 0.5` in `(np.random.rand(10) - 0.5)` ? is it the step?

Comment: `mySound, samplingFreq = sf.read(myAudio)`  `mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]` `samplePoints = float(mySound.shape[0])` I would like x to be `mySoundOneChannel` and t to be `numpy.arange(0, samplePoints, 1) / samplingFreq` Is that possible?

Comment: np.random.rand(10) returns 10 random values in range [0,1]. -0.5 shifts it into range [-0.5, 0.5]. It's there only to show that it doesn't matter if you have values of `x` equally spaced in time or not. Basically `x` and `t`  are there only to provide you with fully working piece of code and you should replace them with your values of `x` and `t`.

Comment: the code is working :) Thank you for taking the effort to explain it to me ! Appreciate it :)

Comment: I get a feeling that the index inversed my t `timeArray`. The result produced 2.82s when 6.26s was expected.

Comment: I used `list(reversed(timeArray))` but that produced 6.057s instead

Comment: You got a wrong feeling. According to documentation both [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)  start indexing from element 0. If you are not sure, then print `x` and `t` from the example above and check if correct value was printed in the for loop (only 10 of them so it's easy to verify).